# Which is the most generic view in Qt Quick Controls 2

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I'm learning to work with QML and Qt Quick Controls 2 and try to figure out how to write "proper" applications with it (endgame is a small prototype for embedded devices).

One thing I'm missing is a simple and explicit way to build multi-page applications: there is `StackView`, `TabView` and `SwipeView`, but there is nothing like `SimpleView`, a component that I could put `Page` components into and then switch them via custom actions. Currently, I'm mis-using the `SwipeView` to achieve something similar, by setting `interactive` property to `false`, but I have to wonder whether this is a proper way.

So, which is the most generic "page container" component in Qt Quick Controls 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`StackLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html) from Qt Quick Layouts. It's a stack of arbitrary items, where you can control the index of the currently visible item.

```
StackLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    currentIndex: 1

    Page {
        // ...
    }

    Page {
        // ...
    }
}
```